# What is the current interpretation of "‘arob", or "עָרוֹב"?

Tags: plagues-makkos

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagues_of_Egypt#4._Mixture_of_wild_animals_or_flies_(%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%A8%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%91):_Ex._8:20-32) that the meaning of the phrase *"‘arob"*, or *"עָרוֹב"*, is disputed.

I have always been taught it as *"flies"* - and that's the word used by the [NIVUK translation of Exodus 8:21](https://www.bible.com/bible/113/EXO.8.21). In the so-called [Orthodox Jewish Bible, Shemot 8:21](https://www.bible.com/bible/130/EXO.8.21) it simply uses *"arov"*, and in the so-called [Complete Jewish Bible, Sh'mot 8:17](https://www.bible.com/bible/1275/EXO.8.17) it says *"swarms of insects"*.

Has there been any more recent interpretation of the word?

Comment: Did you mean to write Shemos 8:20 in those examples?

Comment: Possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13458/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I was kinda hoping for a more modern look at this - has anything changed in 4 years?

Comment: How modern do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Shmuel since the CJB (1998) apparently. See also the OP's comment just above.

Comment: @msh210 ideally since the answer linked above - 2012

Comment: Btw, the "Orthodox Jewish Bible" is _not_ Orthodox at all. It's a Messianic publication guising as something Jewish (again)...

Comment: @Tim I’m pretty sure nothing’s changed about it in over 3300 years.

Answer (score -1):

Jastrow, in accordance with the most common interpretation (as brought from the Midrash, for instance), translates the word עָרוֹב as "various kinds of wild beasts".

[image]

He does mention the possibilty of the word meaning "gadfly".

Comment: The question was "Has there been any more recent interpretation of the word?". I don't see how this answers that.

Comment: "the traditional Rabbinic interpretation" is there only one traditional Rabbinic interpretation?

Comment: @DoubleAA *most common interpretation ^ See edit

Comment: Most common among what? Contemporary Jewish kindergartners? Rishonim?