# Are there any Jewish sources that discuss vampires?

Tags: brit-milah, myths, blood

Are there any sources in Judaism that discuss vampires? I am aware that it is mentioned in the sefer hassidim but have not found any other source material. I am specifically curious if there are any sources that connect it to the metzitzah process during bris milah but I'd be happy with any sources that discuss vampires in general.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5687/1569

Comment: And [this post on Hirhurim](http://torahmusings.com/2011/10/vampires-and-witches-in-sefer-hasidim/) brings the sources for vampires in Sefer Chasidim.

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9197/5

Comment: What can we merge the [tag:vampire] tag into? Surely we don't need one....

Comment: @msh210 perhaps a mythical creatures tag or occult or something more general?

Comment: The werewolf question has [tag:animals] on it.

Comment: I don't know what's more surprising: a question about vampires, or that within minutes two related questions were linked. :-)

Comment: http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2011/12/was-eisav-vampire.html

Comment: http://torahmusings.com/2011/10/vampires-and-witches-in-sefer-hasidim/

Comment: http://torahmusings.com/2012/02/blood-l%E2%80%99mehadrin/

Comment: metzitzah, really? :P how about matzos?

Comment: @jake that's not a source per se.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, I know. Just a related blog post.

Comment: @yoel are you aware of any other ritual in judaism or any other major religion wherein one person must suck blood out of another?

Comment: @nikmasi I really find the comparison very disturbing.  Vampires drink and consume blood, we apply suction to the wound to clean it, and then promptly spit it out. Honestly, I know this wasn't your intention but it really sounds like a comparison the antisemitic opponents of metzitzah would make.

Comment: @yoel my intention was purely academic. To me it would make sense that in antiquity where Jews were already demonized a myth regarding sucking blood which originally stemmed from a misapprehension of metzitzah arose. Let me be clear,  **I 100% personally support metzitzah b'peh, and made sure it was performed for my son** my question is merely to ascertain if there was any scholarship that might demonstrate that the myth of vampires stemmed from a misunderstanding of this ritual.

Comment: @nikmasi thanks for your response, also just to clarify I was definitely not saying that you c'v were holding a negative opinion.  I think I didn't understand that you were looking for secular sources or scholarship in that way, I get it now and withdraw my complaint. :)

Comment: @yoel "we apply suction to the wound to clean it, and then promptly spit it out." I think you mean "we apply suction to the wound to _try and_ clean it _even though we end up actually making it dirtier_, and then promptly spit it out."

Comment: @DoubleAA no, that's not what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/774719/Batya_Edelman/Vampires_and_Werewolves) briefly touches on this subject; the only real substantial additional source she sites is the Seforno to Vayikra 17:4 (though she probably means 17:7, who was prceeded by Rabbeinu Bachya [ben asher] on Dvarim 12:23). Unsourced are claims by Rabbi Menachem Zioni that vampires were associated with migdal bavel and a broad proclamation that according to many kabbalistic leaders there are parallels of these creatures [vampires and werewolves] in Judaism.

Much of what she writes seems to be based on [this short piece](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/Shokel/011025_Vampires.html)published in the Jewish Free Press in 2001 which in turn cites Dan, Joseph. The Esoteric Theology of Ashkenazi Hasidism. Jerusalem: Mosad Bialik, 1968. which I'm guessing is based heavily on the Sefer Hassidim you reference and Trachtenberg, Joshua. [Jewish Magic and Superstition: A Study in Folk Religion](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/jms/index.htm), Temple Books. New York: Atheneum, 1970 but gives no page numbers.

A further study of that latter source reveals references to Rokeaḥ 316 and some additional recent scholarship. Sorry, nothing related to bris milah that I could see.